# Reapply a commit that was undone by conflict?

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

I have this commit that was undone by someone who doesn't know how to deal with conflicts. Is there an easy way to try auto merging the commit back in? I tried using "merge to master" but it just says up to date. I am using tortoisegit.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

That's what [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) is for. It lets you apply changes by using already existing commits.

The basic syntax is:

```sh
git cherry-pick <commit> ...
```

Comment: Amazing! Of course I knew `git cherry-pick`, but I didn't think about using it in this case. Thanks!

Comment: For those wanting to cherry pick a particular commit, you can just do `git cherry-pick [commit number here]`

Comment: What if that person has overwritten 4 of your commits? Can you cherry pick them as a group?

Comment: @Janneman96 AFAICT, `git cherry-pick` can accept more than one commit, but it creates a new commit for each of them. One solution to that would be to then use `git rebase -i` to combine the new commits into one.